# JSON decoding from a URL

Tags: php, json

I'm using an API which returns a JSON string:

http://api.geonames.org/findNearbyPlaceNameJSON?lat=51.9877644&lng=-1.47866&username=demo

The part I'm interested in is the city/town name (in this instance Hook Norton) which I'd like as a PHP variable. I understand the `JSON_decode()` function comes into play somewhere, but how do I access the output of the API?

Comment: Like any other array or object.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Try this.

```
$json = file_get_contents('http://api.geonames.org/findNearbyPlaceNameJSON?lat=51.9877644&lng=-1.47866&username=demo');

$data = json_decode($json,true);

$Geonames = $data['geonames'][0];

echo "<pre>";

print_r($Geonames);

exit;
```

Comment: Thanks very much. How would I set a variable for just one element of the array e.g. town name?

Comment: $Geonames = $data['geonames'][0]['keyname'];

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is to use `file_get_contents`, which works on web documents as well as local files.  For example:

```
$json = file_get_contents("http://api.geonames.org/findNearbyPlaceNameJSON?lat=51.9877644&lng=-1.47866&username=demo");
$data = json_decode($json);
echo $data->geonames[0]->toponymName;
```

Answer (score 1):

Since the JSON is part of the HTTP response, you need to make an HTTP request with PHP and get the response as a string.

The swiss knife for this is [cURL](http://www.php.net/manual/en/curl.examples-basic.php), but (depending on your requirements and the server's PHP configuration) you are likely able to do this very simply like this:

```
$json = file_get_contents('http://api.geonames.org/findNearbyPlaceNameJSON?lat=51.9877644&lng=-1.47866&username=demo');
$data = json_decode($json);
// and now access the data you need
```